# Vocabulary alignment in LDflex

Tags: linked-data, json

From https://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2018/12/28/designing-a-linked-data-developer-experience/#ldflex-feeling:

> If you are dealing with a different type of data, you cannot use them. This is odd, since Linked Data can model anything.
>   They assume that objects have a specific set of properties. This is a major restriction, since Linked Data enables arbitrary data shapes.

I don't use LDflex, so my "issue" is just theoretical, musing about the citation from your blog post:
say, I want to query RDF profiles, where one profile uses `foaf` and the other uses `schema` as namespace for the `name` property - how would you access the data? Tricky "vocabulary alignment" via one jsonld-context is not allowed, for json-keys have to be unique:

`{
  "@context": {
    "name": "http://foaf.org/name",
    "name": "http://schema.org/name"
  }`

Because of this it's probably also not allowed to write two `context.jsonld` with *one* key referencing two different properties. 
In other words, what to do to get this SPARQL, resp. how to get the idea behind it:

`SELECT ?friend ?name   WHERE {
  { ?friend foaf:name ?name. }
  UNION { ?friend schema:name ?name }.
}`

Comment: This comment seems to be related: https://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2017/12/20/paradigm-shifts-for-the-decentralized-web/#comment-3715829969

Comment: Good pointing, somehow I have missed the comment section at the post. Added a back-reference there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long-term answer here is reasoning based on ontologies.

A JSON-LD context alone indeed won't get us there. However, the ontological equivalence between `foaf:name` and `schema:name` can allow the LDflex internals to derive the SPARQL query you provide in the example. Currently, only the simple SPARQL query without union would be derived.

However, this is the long term only; there are still quite some things to tackle (notably shapes) before we should dive into reasoning.